# How can I make vscode installed with flatpak able to use internal terminals to run certain programs in the system?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flatpak

By looking up some information, I know that the programs installed by flatpak are all running in the sandbox. Is there a way to make the sandbox environment search for some of the system environment to type content?

The program I want to use in vscode's integrated terminal is located under /usr/libexec/tmp. But the path cannot be searched in vscode's integrated terminal. However, it can be searched in an external terminal and can run programs.

Can you do some configuration in vscode using flatpak installation to accomplish the above goals?

I tried to install Code-OSS using the aur source, and the code-OSS terminal is synchronized with the system terminal environment.

However, Code-OSS cannot log in using a github account.

Answer (score 4):

In your vscode `settings.json` file add the following, it basically adds access to the `zsh` and `bash` terminals and sets `zsh` as the default

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
            "icon": "terminal-bash",
            "args": [
                "--host",
                "--env=TERM=xterm-256color",
                "bash"
            ]
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
            "args": [
                "--host",
                "--env=TERM=xterm-256color",
                "zsh"
            ]
        },
    },
```

To make your extensions pick your environment php, you can also add

```json
"php.validate.executablePath": "/run/host/usr/bin/php",
```